# Enable jmx monitor for EhCache in osgi env

Tags: hibernate, osgi, ehcache, jmx, karaf

I am working on OSGI based application which runs on Karaf. We use JPA and Hibernate to connect to mysql . Have enabled Level 2 cache using Ehcache. I want  to enable JMX monitoring of Ehcache. I found an article which tells how to enable on JMX monitoring of Ehcache on Spring application (http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/How-to-monitor-Ehcache-in-JMX-with-Spring-Configuration).

Is there a way to configure JMX monitoring of EHcache on OSGI application running on Karaf similar to example  above ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you do not create the `CacheManager` yourself, Hibernate does.
So you have to either:

- Plug into the Hibernate second level cache initialisation to get at the `CacheManager` and run the `ManagementService.registerMBeans` that the article talks about. You may be able to do that by extending the Hibernate Ehcache provider so that it adds that initialisation step. See `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`.
- Find a logical place in your application startup where the `CacheManager` has already been created by Hibernate, get at it using the `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager#ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS` map, and perform the MBeans initialisation as in the article.